# Problema ao criar projeto Symfony

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer, symfony

Estou com um problema para iniciar um projeto, sempre aparece o erro:

```
henrique@henrique-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB:~/Documents$ composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony
```

Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.99)
  - Installing symfony/skeleton (v3.4.99)
    Loading from cache

Created project in symfony
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.4.5)
    Loading from cache

Some Symfony Flex features may not work as expected: your version of Composer is too old
Please upgrade using https://getcomposer.org/
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (60cdb79275d49529df6e9eeba183f7da)
  - Configuring symfony/flex (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Composer\Json\JsonManipulator::removeMainKey() in /home/henrique/Documents/symfony/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php:362
Stack trace:

## 0 /home/henrique/Documents/symfony/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php(320): Symfony\Flex\Flex->update()

## 1 [internal function]: Symfony\Flex\Flex->checkForUpdate(Object(Composer\Script\PackageEvent))

## 2 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(171): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Script\PackageEvent))

## 3 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(114): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\PackageEvent))

## 4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(590): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchPackageEvent('post-package-in...', true, Object(Composer\DependencyResolver\DefaultPolicy), Object(Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool), Object(Composer\Repository\CompositeRepository), Object(Composer\DependencyResolver\Request), Array, Object(Composer\DependencyReso in /home/henrique/Documents/symfony/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php on line 362

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Composer\Json\JsonManipulator::removeMainKey() in /home/henrique/Documents/symfony/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php:362
Stack trace:

## 0 /home/henrique/Documents/symfony/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php(320): Symfony\Flex\Flex->update()

## 1 [internal function]: Symfony\Flex\Flex->checkForUpdate(Object(Composer\Script\PackageEvent))

## 2 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(171): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Script\PackageEvent))

## 3 /usr/share/php/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(114): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\PackageEvent))

## 4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(590): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchPackageEvent('post-package-in...', true, Object(Composer\DependencyResolver\DefaultPolicy), Object(Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool), Object(Composer\Repository\CompositeRepository), Object(Composer\DependencyResolver\Request), Array, Object(Composer\DependencyReso in /home/henrique/Documents/symfony/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Flex.php on line 362

Comment: atualiza seu composer

Answer (score 0):

Conforme mensagem na saída do comando:

> your version of Composer is too old Please upgrade

a versão do composer está muito desatualizada, é necessário atualizar para criar um projeto symfony.

**Comando para atualizar a versão do composer:**

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

**Documentação do composer:**

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-